# Cannot access the AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an instance on AWS. I used Remote Desktop connection to deploy an application on Tomcat. On the remote server, I can use http://localhost/myapp to open and run the application. In the EC2 Console, I edited the Security Groups, i.e., edit inbound rules, and allow HTTP (port 80). However, I still cannot access the application via http://**.**.**.**/myapp (**.**.**.** is the public ip). I have also tried to allow all traffic from anywhere, and it still didn't work.

Can anyone give me any advices? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you still have the windows firewall in place?

Comment: Do you mean the windows firewall on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, windows instances do have a firewall that also needs to be opened. You could also disable it and use just the security group instead.

Comment: Just a comment, when I first time turn off the windows firewall, I cannot remote connect to the server. I had to stop and start the instance. Then I changed the start style of windows firewall to manual.